# OData v4 Client Code Generator - Only Certain Endpoints

Tags: c#, odata, generator, odata-v4

I'm using the [OData v4 Client Code Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bingl.ODatav4ClientCodeGenerator) to generate an ODATA feed.

It's working fine but the feed itself has hundreds of endpoints and I'm on interested in it wrapping a few of them.

Is there an easy way to alter the generator to only include endpoints starting with X?